# Dependency injection without passing objects in functions in Flutter using GetX?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

Dependency injection is all about passing objects to a class **through either a constructor or a setter function**.

So, if we use **GetX** then for dependency injection, the way would be to use **Get.put()**.

But we aren't passing the object **through any function** to the following class so how can this be classified as "dependency injection"?

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {        
  Controller controller = Get.put(Controller());    
}
```

Now, if we have to pass another controller to this class from another class (using GetX), how do we do it?

[https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-flutter-getx-ecosystem-dependency-injection-8e763d0ec6b9#:~:text=Dependency%20Injection%20is%20the%20technique,code%20at%20a%20greater%20level](https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-flutter-getx-ecosystem-dependency-injection-8e763d0ec6b9#:%7E:text=Dependency%20Injection%20is%20the%20technique,code%20at%20a%20greater%20level).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of dependency injection is that once a controller has been initialized in any widget, Later widgets if need the controller they can simply get and not put every time.

```
Controller1 objectName=Get.find();
```

To try this, create a widget on page 1 and initialize the controller (PUT), create a button and send to page 2 and try to get the controller there. You will notice, that the controller is available instead of using put in all subsequent pages.

For using multiple controllers:

```
Controller1 controller1 = Get.put(Controller1());  
Controller2 controller2 = Get.put(Controller2());
```

Note GetX knows the controller because on your controller class you write:

```
class Controller1 extends GetxController
```